# iOS swift animation position + constraint

Tags: ios, swift, animation

This is the structure of my views: A top view vertically over a bottom view. There is a constraint between the two views, and there is an X that sets the vertical distance of the views to 0.

I'm doing an animation to move out (in the top side) of the top view. Doing that that bottom view should automatically move up because of the constraint.

But while the top view is going out. The bottom view remains fixed.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
func hideTopSection() {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.topSectionView.center.y = -self.topSectionView.bounds.height
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Autolayout changing of frames, positions, bounds etc. has no effect, because Autolayout will overwrite your modifications during the next layout step. You have to change the constraints in order to modify the layout. In your case: Change the constant of the top constraint of `self.topSectionView`.

Answer (score 2):

Frame-layout will not help as it won't force positioning related elements , try auto-layout so , Hook the top constraint of topView as IBOutlet say `topViewTopCon`

```
func hideTopSection() {

    self.topViewTopCon.constant = -1 * self.topSectionView.bounds.height

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }, completion: nil)
}
```